# GDK Immersion/Live Card push notification

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-glass, google-mirror-api, google-gdk

Is there any way to send a push notification to a native GDK Immersion application (or to a LiveCard based application)? As far as I have read, Glass doesn't support play services for GCM push notifications - is this correct?  In our application we have server-side events that need to be responded to by the application.  Any samples I've seen of this nature tend to use the Mirror API.

I've seen some people creating hybrid applications where they push a card using the Mirror API and have this invoke the native application (through using a custom url protocol).  This seems a little cumbersome to me and I wanted to check there wasn't a better way to do this.  For our specific requirements I also don't see any way that a user who is in our Immersion application would get notified of the update, bar closing and viewing the new card on the timeline.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that GCM requires Google Play Services, which is not available on Glass as of XE16, but there are some work arounds.

- You can use the deprecated, but still functional, [C2DM API](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/?csw=1).
- Pull your remote server on using a [ScheduledthreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) or equivalent API

However, your proposed solution involving the Mirror API isn't going to work. Your GDK Glassware does not have local access to your user's timeline.

Comment: Not exactly, GCM works fine if you use gcm.jar library instead of GCM included in Google Play Services. I was using this solution on XE12 in order to publish cards with TimelineManager. Unfortunately it has been removed...

Answer (score 0):

I have used the GCM push notification using the gcm.jar. It is working fine in Google Glass.
You want to display the notification message in the Live card.